# How to create class from inside a class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

How can we create a class from a function inside a class?

```
class One {
  CreateClass() {
    return class Two {
      init() {
          console.log(1234567)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We look to create a class from an already created class instance like this:

```
var one = new Class();
var two = new one.CreateClass();
two.init();
```

Comment: (Use objects instead?) Do you want to return a new instance, or a class object?

Comment: We want to return a new instance.

Comment: Move Two outside One, and return `new Two` in `CreateClass`?

Comment: `TypeError: (new one()).CreateClass is not a constructor`

Comment: Replace with `two = one.CreateClass()` instead? Although I still don't understand quite why this is needed.

Comment: `TypeError: one.CreateClass is not a constructor`

Comment: It's needed for such use cases: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3.html#id12

Comment: May you update your question? Debugging line-by-line isn't fun.

Comment: Can you just do this https://jsfiddle.net/y1whgx5q/ ?

Comment: @NenadVracar off site links are not useful to other users of this site. Especially when those links become broken.

Comment: @NenadVracar it worked. Maybe, respond to it as an "answer" so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Your `One1.createClass()` is not a constructor function it's return value is. So you need to invoke it and then call new on return value

```js
class One {
  CreateClass() {
    return class Two {
      init() {
        console.log(1234567)
      }
    }
  }
}


var One1 = new One();
var two = new (One1.CreateClass())()
two.init();
```

---

I am not entirely sure how you want but you can do something like this

```js
function One() {
  this.CreateClass = class Two {
    init() {
      console.log(1234567)
    }
  }
}


var One1 = new One();
var two = new One1.CreateClass()
two.init();
```

Comment: Is there any way to just do like `One1.CreateClass()` something similar to this: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3.html#id12

Comment: @SowmayJain look at the second snippet, is this what you want to achieve ?

Comment: The prior version suits best. Is there any way to access the functions in `Class One` inside the new instance of `Class Two`?  `this.functionName` doesn't work as this not relates to `Class Two`.

Comment: @SowmayJain you can extend class two from class one, `class Two extends One`

Answer (score 1):

You could add `new` keyword after `return` statement so that it invokes class `Two` on each call of `CreateClass` method and returns the new instance of the class `Two`.

```js
class One {
  CreateClass() {
    return new class Two {
      init() {
        console.log(1234567)
      }
    }
  }
}

var one = new One();
var two = one.CreateClass();
two.init();
```